# How do i compare some items in a ListBox with a string value

Tags: c#, listbox

I am creating a program that is supposed to compare a name that the user  enters with a bank of names in a list box. The program has to compare all of the names one by one, letter by letter to find the best match. How am I supposed to select a value in the list box to compare it with the string? And how can I compare letter by letter?

```
 private void btnRechercher_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (txtName.Text.Length == 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Enter a name.", "Error");
        }
        else
        {
            txtName.Text = txtName.Text.ToUpper();

            string sName = txtName.ToString();
            byte byEquivalentLetters = 0;

            if (this.lstName.Items.Count > 0)
            {
                {
                    if (chkExactResearch.Checked == true)
                    {
                        while (txtName.TextLength != 0)
                        {
                            // What do I write here?
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Note that in my code

txtName = LEA\r\nEMMA\r\nOLIVIA\r\nFLORENCE

Comment: Do you want to get the value with closest matching list name or do you want to check if exact same name exist in the list or not ?

Comment: I need to check, letter by letter, if it is the same letter.

Comment: Are you using winform or wpf?

Comment: I am using a winform platform on visual studio.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming txtName is TextBox. If you want just find exact same string, this code should work on any version of .Net

```
        int foundIndex;
        if ((foundIndex = lstName.Items.IndexOf(txtName.Text)) != -1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(lstName.Items[foundIndex].ToString());
        }
```

IndexOf() return the zero-based index where the item is located within the collection; otherwise, negative one (-1)

[IndexOf()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listbox.objectcollection.indexof?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: I am supposed to compare letter by letter and find the names that has the same letters (alex and lexa for instance).